# How to override enumeration data in rail_admin gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-admin

In my models, BookHeader has many Category
So, when edit or create new BookHeader, the form show like this
[Enum fix?](http://nr7.upanh.com/b3.s32.d2/89392864d0eb4a6e3988ab7b137ff7fa_50339337.catetgoryfix.png)

I wanna change the "category #{id}" to category name by define a category_enum method but it still don't work. Please help!

Code for BookHeader model

```
class BookHeader < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :autho, :category_id, :description, :title, :book_type, :year,:publisher_id,:detail
  has_many :books
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :publisher
  TYPE = {:ebook=>"Ebook",:paper_book=> "PaperBook",:magazine=> "Magazine",:media=> "Media"}
  DEFAULT_TAB = :paper_book
  BOOKS_PER_PAGE = 1 # books to show in a pages (pagination)
  extend FriendlyId
  def book_type_enum #it worked here
    TYPE.map{|key, val| [val]}
  end
  def category_enum #but dont' work here
    ["a","b"]
  end
```

Code for edit form

```
edit do
        field :title
        field :description, :text do
          ckeditor do true end
        end
        field :autho
        field :book_type
        field :category
      end
```

See the Division attribute in [this link](http://rails-admin-tb.herokuapp.com/admin/team/73/edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alias_attribute :name, :you_field_you_want_to_display
```

I think it's more flexible way, there is no need to rename something and everything will work properly

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I just found the answer, rename a column in your model to "name", it seem to be very magical, but it worked!